# Grails save() method bug

Tags: grails, dns, save, grails-orm

For example I have entity person saved in db with the name John and id 1 then:

```
def person = Person.get(1) 
person.name = 'Maria'
person.save()

//after that name still will be John
//but if I save one more time than name be Maria
```

Addition information is that my domain have inside service, and method that work with this service.
I don't now in what is a problem, maybe somebody had already this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not flushed at this moment, changes kept in memory for a while. If you need to force Grails to update DB exactly at this moment, add `flush: true` parameter:

```
person.save(flush: true)
```

Comment: ok, also add `failOnError: true`, maybe you have an error? as I see you didn't check `.save()` result for errors

Comment: enable `showSql` in `DataSource.groovy` and see if it really makes this `UPDATE`